# How to fetch single XElement from list of IEnumerable<XElement> using linq

Tags: c#-4.0, linq-to-xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Document>
  <State Code="A" Type="B">
    <Info>     
      <FirstName ripName="Hello"></FirstName>
      <LastName  ripName="Word"></LastName>
    </Info>
  </State>
</Document>
```

For this xml i am trying to fetch FirstName attribute value using linq as per below code snippet but i am getting null.

```
IEnumerable<XElement> a1 = xmlData.Elements("State").Where(c => c.Attribute("Code").Value.Equals("A") && c.Attribute("Type").Value.Equals("B"))
                                    .Elements("Info");

var x1 = a1.Select(x => x.Element("FirstName").Attribute("ripName")).FirstOrDefault();
```

x1 is null, please suggest.

Comment: Nope, with that code and that XML, with `var xmlData = XElement.Load(...)`, `ripName` is not null. Please show a [mcve] that actually demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If I suppose that xmlData is an XDocument loaded with the xml that you show, the main problem is here : `xmlData.Elements("State")...` is empty. If you want the element "State" you should use `xmlData.Descendants("State")`.

And select the value of attribute like this :

```
var x2 = a1.Select(x => x.Element("FirstName").Attribute("ripName")).FirstOrDefault().Value;
```

Or

```
string x1 = a1.Elements("FirstName").FirstOrDefault().Attribute("ripName").Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

In VB it would look like this, if I understand what you are trying to do,

```
    Dim xe As XElement

    'to load from file
    '  xe=XElement.Load("your path here")

    'to test
    xe = <Document>
             <State Code="A" Type="B">
                 <Info>
                     <FirstName ripName="Hello"></FirstName>
                     <LastName ripName="World"></LastName>
                 </Info>
             </State>
         </Document>

    Dim ie As IEnumerable(Of XElement)

    ie = From el In xe.Elements
         Where el.@Code = "A" AndAlso el.@Type = "B"
            From sel In el.<Info>.Elements
            Where sel.Name.LocalName = "FirstName"
            Select sel Take 1

    Dim attrRN As XAttribute
    If ie.Count = 1 Then
        attrRN = ie.FirstOrDefault.Attribute("ripName")
        Debug.WriteLine(attrRN.Value)
    End If
```

This of course assumes that you have given an accurate portrayl of the XML.